# file closes in current folder and show in workspace folder

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I click a file in a subfolder, the explorer displays the file in workspace folder and the subfolder closes automatically. For example,

[image]

When I click "test1.py" under "test1" folder, explorer shows it under "testspace" and closes "test1" folder.

How can I disable this behavior?

Here is the structure of my folder:

```
testspace/
  testspace.code-workspace
  test1/
    test1.py
  test2/
    test2.py
```

Contents of testspace.code-workspace:

```
{
    "folders": [
        {"path": "."},
        {"path": "test1"},
        {"path": "test2"}
    ],
    "settings": {
        "files.exclude": {
            "test1": true,
            "test2": true,
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `feature` is called auto focus which can be disabled in settings.json.